# Codeigniter routing help, backlinking to previous directories

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

the site in question is http://www.ziplinegolive.com/

I have built this in CI and currently there is 2 "views" folders

-pages
and 
-news

I want to make a news directory to organize my posts and not have them interfere with the other pages. My problem that im having though is once i enter http://www.ziplinegolive.com/news/home I noticed that when i check my header links...all the urls acquire the news/ directory...which doestn allow me to go back.... does anyone know how i can fix this? i currently have one routes config files and 2 controllers.

first here is my routes.php

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

here is my standard pages controller

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function view($page = 'home')
{
  if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
{
    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
    show_404();
}

$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
}
```

and here is my news controller

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
{

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

  $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('news/'.$page);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);


}

}
```

ive been busting my head in to try and figure this out.... any help is GREATLY appreciated!

thank you!

UPDATE: ADDED HEADER.PHP - as you can see the css and js files are static linked because of this routing debacle....

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>ZipLine™</title>
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,    user-scalable=no" />
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
 <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
 <!-- All Animations CSS -->
 <link href="http://www.ziplinegolive.com/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!-- Image Lightbox CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ziplinegolive.com/css/imagelightbox.css"      type="text/css" media="screen">
 <!-- Theme styles and Menu styles -->
 <link href="http://www.ziplinegolive.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://www.ziplinegolive.com/css/mainmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!-- Call Fontawsome Icon Font from a CDN -->
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-     awesome/4.1.0/http://www.ziplinegolive.com/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

 <!--FlexSlider -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/woothemes-FlexSlider-06b12f8/flexslider.css"      type="text/css" media="screen">
 <!--Isotope Plugin -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/isotope/http://www.ziplinegolive.com/css/style.css"      type="text/css" media="screen">
 <!--Simple Text Rotator -->
 <link href="http://www.ziplinegolive.com/css/simpletextrotator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <!--Modernizer Custom -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.48287.js"></script>
 <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-fa-57x57-precomposed.png">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
 </head>
 <body class="sticky_header">
 <div class="overflow_wrapper">
 <header>
      <div class="container">
           <div class="logo"><a class="brand" href="index.html"><img      src="http://www.ziplinegolive.com/images/logo.png" alt="optional logo"></a></div>

           <!-- MAIN MENU -->

           <div id="mainmenu" class="menu_container">
                <label class="mobile_collapser">MENU</label>
                <!-- Mobile menu title -->
                <ul>
                     <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                     <div class="dmui_dropdown_block">
                               <ul class="dmui-submenu">
                                    <li><a href="about">The Company</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="media">Media</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="partners">Partners</a></li>
                               </ul>
                          </div>

                     </li>
                      <li><a href="products">Products and Services</a></li>
                     <li><a href="news">News</a></li>
                     <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>

           <!-- /MAIN MENU -->

           <div class="triangle-up-left"></div>
           <div class="triangle-up-right"></div>
      </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: Can you post your header.php?

Comment: Hi Verba! yes i just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your links.

For example

```
<li><a href="about">The Company</a></li> 
=> 
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('about');?>">The Company</a></li>
```

And also, you can link to css/js files like this:

```
 <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets');?>/css/mainmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This of course expects that you have your css files in project/assets/css

Comment: ummm when i do that my site seems to break... i just changed the about link- take a look at the site now

Comment: the page seems to load all the way up to that link now... :/

Comment: Enable URL helper in your autoload.php

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array();
?? what do i change that too? this is the confusing part im thinking

Comment: i added $this->load->helper('url'); to the array() but nothing.... im pretty lost here

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Comment: ok cool its working but im noticing ONE MORE THING.... the behavior of some of the links changes as you click around.... i dont know if you can see but if you go to ziplinegolive.com the about section has the drop down....then as soon as you click over to the next page...it loses that and images dont get displayed.... i think this has something to do with index.php in the url which i removed from my htdocs... im assuming i have to set a base url without index.php?

Comment: Uhm.. did you delete the actual index.php file from your codeigniter application root?

Comment: Anyway. Here you find how to remove index.php from url: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html "Removing the index.php file"

Comment: ok yeah thats my new problem how can i get this <?php echo site_url('about');?> code to not include this damn index.php ..... ummm not that i think of... in my application/ folder all i have is index.html but i dont see any index.php

Comment: Yeah. Do that .htaccess stuff and check that in your config.php file is like this "$config['index_page'] = '';"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67570/discussion-between-verba-and-tetzuro).